# How to control assignments order in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, variable-assignment

I have implemented some tensor initializations as assigmnets in Tensowrflow graph. Simultaneously, these assignments should be called in correct order, because ones use results of anothers. If I expose assignment nodes to outside, user (myself too) should run them with session call

```
sess.run([assign1, assign2, ...])
```

in correct orded and can mistake. Can I join the sequence of assignments into single operation and expose only it run?

**UPDATE**

I wrote this code and found it prints eye? Why? It should print random inits of `b`, shouldn't it?

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

a = tf.eye(2, 2)
b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=(2,2))
c = tf.get_variable("c", shape=(2,2))

assign_c = tf.assign(c, b)
assign_b = tf.assign(b, a)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    sess.run([assign_c, assign_b])

    print(c.eval())
```

**UPDATE 2**

The code below shows I can't control assignmen order with [`group`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

a = tf.eye(2, 2)
b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=(2,2), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
c = tf.get_variable("c", shape=(2,2))

assign_c = tf.assign(c, b)
assign_b = tf.assign(b, a)

incorrect_init = tf.group(assign_b, assign_c)
correct_init = tf.group(assign_c, assign_b)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    sess.run([incorrect_init])
    #sess.run([correct_init])

    print(c.eval())
```

Result is always

```
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
```

regardless I call `correct_init` or `incorrect_init`. Why? How to force order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the variables in a single `sess.run` call doesn't mean anything.

```
sess.run([assign1, assign2, ...])
```

it equivalent to

```
sess.run([..., assign2, assign1, ...])
```

what really matters are the relationship among the nodes you're executing.

In your example, the output of `c.eval()` is eye, because:

1. sess.run([assign_c, assign_b]) invokes `assign_c` and `assign_b`.
2. `assign_b` depends on `a`.
3. `assign_c` depends on `b`.
4. thus `c` depends on `b` that depends on `a`

Thus: -> resolve `a` first.

Comment: Okay, so how to control order? Does order matter in tf.group?

Comment: Also I don't see how it implies that `c` depends on `b`

Comment: `c` depends on `b` because you're assigning the value of `b` to `c`.  But `b` depends on `a` because you're assigning the value of `a` to `b`. Hence, the sequence of resolutions forces the evaluation of `a` first and then any other op that depends on it. You can't force any other when dependencies among nodes are present. Period. Instead, you could use `tf.control_dependencies` if no dependencies are present. If you really want to "break" the dependencies, you have to execute with **different** `sess.run` single nodes, in the order you desire.

Comment: so, assigments in Tensorflow are better regarded as not actual assignments of values, but assigning a reference or reconnecting the graph?

Comment: Exactly, you're drawing a line among nodes and this line is a relation that forces an order

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.group](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) to group operators. Tensorflow will resolve all dependencies for you if there are any.

**UPDATE**

```
c <- assign_c =>
c <- b =>
c <- assign_b =>
c <- a
```

even if you omit `sess.run([assign_c, assign_b])` step.

**UPDATE 2**
If you need to keep execution order for 3 independent Tensors or Operators you may do it with [control_dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies), but ONLY if there are no any dependencies.

```
with tf.control_dependencies([first]):
    op1 = tf.no_op()
with tf.control_dependencies([op1, second]):
    op2 = tf.no_op()
with tf.control_dependencies([op2, third]):
    op3 = tf.no_op()

with tf.Session() as s:
    op3.aval()
```

Comment: See my update please. I came accross `group` myself, but before I tested example without it and found it works somehow.